# xcode storyboard nested table pass array

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard, nested-table

I have taken a sample script of an app similar to pulse from the internet which is made up of xib files and I have structured it to go into storyboard to make use of horizontal table scrolling.

For some reason "cell = tableViewCell" in tableView.m keeps failing on me with an assertion failure UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

If I comment out "cell = tableViewCell" the program runs without failure but I do not get the information across to the tableViewCell.

Is there a simple solution that I just cannot see?

tableView.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


       CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
       tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.transform = rotateTable;
       tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.frame.size.width, tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.frame.size.height);

       tableViewCell.contentArray = [arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

       tableViewCell.horizontalTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
       cell = tableViewCell;

     return cell;
 }
```

tableViewCell.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.horizontalTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   for (UIImageView *view in cell.subviews) {
       [view removeFromSuperview];
   }

   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
   imageView.image = [contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

   CGAffineTransform rotateImage = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
   imageView.transform = rotateImage;

   [cell addSubview:imageView];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: the actual error is "'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Answer (score 0):

You should only alloc and init a new table cell if dequeue returns nil.

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}
```

The example you are using http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/ is really old and for iOS 4. Last year in iOS 6 Apple added Collection Views to do these types of things.

You should check out:

WWW2012 Session 205: Introducing Collection Views
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205

Lecture 7 Collection Views
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Comment: ok. but how could I transfer the contentArray from tableView to horizontaltableView Cell (nested tables)

Comment: I guess I'm not getting exactly what your doing, what is the url of the example you used?

Comment: http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/

Comment: @gr I updated the answer that example is really old there are much better ways to do that.

Comment: to use a collection view would be great but there is limited information on getting the view to work much like the "pulse" app or "app store featured items". also may not work prior to ios6

Comment: Yes Collection Views and autolayout require iOS 6